# Robocopy Error - "a required privilege is not held by the client"

Tags: robocopy

When I try to synchronize the destination folder with the source folder using this robocopy command:

```
robocopy "\\Source\Folder" "\\Destination\Folder" /E /ZB /X /PURGE /COPY /TEE /LOG:D:\log.txt
```

I got this error:

> a required privilege is not held by the client

Even if I have the permission to copy the file from the source folder, I am getting this error message.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

It worked after adding DATSO in COPY switch

```
robocopy "\\Source\Folder" "\\Destination\Folder" /E /ZB /X /PURGE /COPY:DATSO /TEE /LOG:D:\log.txt
```

Meaning of switches used in above command explained below.

/E :: copy subdirectories, including Empty ones.

/ZB :: use restartable mode; if access denied use Backup mode.

/COPYALL :: COPY ALL file info (equivalent to /COPY:DATSOU).

/PURGE :: delete dest files/dirs that no longer exist in source.

/X :: report all eXtra files, not just those selected.

/TEE :: output to console window, as well as the log file.

/LOG:file :: output status to LOG file (overwrite existing log).