# jib gradle plugin + static docker client: cannot build image due to permission error: layer.tar: A required privilege is not held by the client

Tags: docker, jib

I want to build Docker image with jib Gradle plugin in Windows, and use a Windows docker client to load it into my WSL 2 container running `dockerd`, and use WSL 2 as server. Resource-wise I think this is the lightest solution. .

On WSL 2 side, I run `dockerd` service in Ubuntu 20 on WSL 2, and it's listening on `[::]:2375`. TLS disabled(`--tls=false`), only http.

On Windows side, I only downloaded the Docker client(static client, from https://download.docker.com/win/static/stable/x86_64/), and added the dynamic WSL 2 container IP into the `insecure-registry` in `daemon.json`. This file is put in the same dir of `docker.exe` client.

On Intellij IDEA side, I use gradle 5.2.1 wrapper, and jib plugin 3.2.1. I configure jib as follows:

```yaml
jib {
    dockerClient.executable = 'E:\\coding\\environment\\docker\\docker.exe'
    dockerClient.environment = [ DOCKER_HOST: '172.21.169.180:2375',
                                 DOCKER_INSECURE_REGISTRIES: "172.21.169.180:5000"]
    from.image = 'docker://mini/java@sha256:d3ded1fd0df592c33185d930d976304994bbc539c7bf70a6091cb3da0f7e11fa'
    to.image = 'spring-plugins-demo'
    container.mainClass = 'dev.westerngun.oldway.ApplicationV1'
}
```

I know it can connect to dockerd in my WSL 2, because before I add the dynamic IP of Ubuntu the error was not able to connect to daemon. Now it can load the base image and start building.

Then, when I run `jibDockerBuild  --stacktrace`, I see this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':jibDockerBuild'.
> com.google.cloud.tools.jib.plugins.common.BuildStepsExecutionException: C:\Users\WESTER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\16164656866093264693\33e3f3775358985441c3bea658f06f5307326c83f9c0bcbf8aa4acb327abffde\layer.tar: �ͻ���û���������Ȩ��

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':jibDockerBuild'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:117)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:184)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveIncrementalChangesTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveIncrementalChangesTaskExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.google.cloud.tools.jib.plugins.common.BuildStepsExecutionException: C:\Users\WESTER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\16164656866093264693\33e3f3775358985441c3bea658f06f5307326c83f9c0bcbf8aa4acb327abffde\layer.tar: �ͻ���û���������Ȩ��

    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:106)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:705)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:672)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$4.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:338)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:327)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:312)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:133)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.lambda$execute$5(CacheStep.java:83)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.PrepareCachingStep.execute(PrepareCachingStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:23)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:95)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:88)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: com.google.cloud.tools.jib.plugins.common.BuildStepsExecutionException: C:\Users\WESTER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\16164656866093264693\33e3f3775358985441c3bea658f06f5307326c83f9c0bcbf8aa4acb327abffde\layer.tar: �ͻ���û���������Ȩ��

    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.plugins.common.JibBuildRunner.runBuild(JibBuildRunner.java:285)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.gradle.BuildDockerTask.buildDocker(BuildDockerTask.java:126)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\WESTER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\16164656866093264693\33e3f3775358985441c3bea658f06f5307326c83f9c0bcbf8aa4acb327abffde\layer.tar: �ͻ���û���������Ȩ��

    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.tar.TarExtractor.extract(TarExtractor.java:93)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.tar.TarExtractor.extract(TarExtractor.java:49)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.LocalBaseImageSteps.cacheDockerImageTar(LocalBaseImageSteps.java:217)
    at com.google.cloud.tools.jib.builder.steps.LocalBaseImageSteps.lambda$retrieveDockerDaemonLayersStep$0(LocalBaseImageSteps.java:133)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:131)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:74)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:82)
```

The error message in Chinese is

```
C:\Users\WESTER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\16164656866093264693\33e3f3775358985441c3bea658f06f5307326c83f9c0bcbf8aa4acb327abffde\layer.tar: 客户端没有所需的特权。
```

And I think it can be translated into "A required permission is not held by the client".

I suspect this is because my user is not added to `docker-user` group, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66099983/docker-cp-a-required-privilege-is-not-held-by-the-client-errorgcp). But, I uninstalled Docker toolbox and I don't see this group anymore, as it sets `DOCKER_HOST` and interferes with my setup. Secondly, I don't have `Local Users and Group` available, seems Windows 10 Home edition does not have it.

Should I try to install `gpedit` in my Home Edition, add the group and try? But without Docker toolbox, I doubt it would work. Docker documentation explains here that it creates the group and configure it to ensure separation of permissions between root/admin and non-root/non-admin users; I think only creating that group will not work. https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/permission-requirements/

---

But, when I use `docker.exe` to connect to WSL 2 and save a tar file to `C:\Users\WESTER~1\AppData\Local\Temp`, it works. The tar file is created and not corrupted. So I think it's not a permission error; anyone can access that dir.

---

Windows bundled bsd-`tar.exe` has nothing to do with it; renaming the tar.exe in `System32` and build, the error is the same.

Comment: I know there is a solution using Docker Desktop for Windows, Edge edition with native support, but DDfW is the last thing I would try.. that consumes too much resources. I think now my approach resource-wise is much lighter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved when I run `cmd` as admin and `cd` to project dir and do `gradlew jibDockerBuild`. Image built and loaded into WSL 2 daemon successfully. It is indeed file system permission error.

Although still very strange(as I allowed the permission to everyone on that folder), but at least this is one workaround.

---

Another workaround, even better:

As per https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4983, I changed the jib config to set docker host to be `http://[::1]:2375`, and suddenly it works. Seems only ipv6 is bind.

Now not only the host is reachable, even permission error disappears; no insecure_registries settings needed, neither.